# PHP Template Buffering in a Loop

Tags: php, buffering

I'm basically running a loop on a query and using PHP's buffering to insert a template file in the loop.  The problem is if I have more than one result in my query I end up with two or more identical results (loops the same data rather than the next in the mysql result row).

the function...

```
function get_blocks(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `my_table`";
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($results){
        extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);
        ob_start();
        include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates/infoBlock.php');
        $returnString .= ob_get_clean();
    }
    echo $returnString;
}
```

The template looks like:

```
<div>
    Hi my name is <?php echo $name; ?>
    <br>
    and my age is <?php echo $age; ?>
</div>
```

So, if I have two records:

```
record 1
name: Joe
age: 42

record 2
name: Sam
age: 35
```

I end up with

```
Hi my name is Joe
and my age is 42


Hi my name is Joe
and my age is 42
```

instead of

```
Hi my name is Joe
and my age is 42


Hi my name is Sam
and my age is 35
```

I've already tried

```
echo ob_get_clean();
```

and taking $returnString out of the function to no avail...

thoughts?

Comment: I think I just figured it out... it's the EXTR_SKIP

Comment: You can post that as an answer and accept it, if that solves your problem. This will help future readers of this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overlooking the EXTR_SKIP parameter in the extract function. EXTR_SKIP causes any variables that are already set to NOT be overwritten (a bit of a security feature so far as I know)